# Overflow a table cell vertically in a horizontally scrollable table

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html-table, overflow

I'm trying to expand a React dropdown component and make it visible outside of the table. The table has to be horizontally scrollable. 
I'm using the react-dropdown-select component. 
Here is the Codepen I made to indicate the problem (https://codesandbox.io/s/great-banach-48yt5)

Changing the outer Div property from

```
overflow: auto
```

To

```
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: visible
```

Doesn't work. Indicated in : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6433475/9358897

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you're sticking with the react-dropdown-select package, [it has an option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropdown-select#api) to render the dropdown within a [portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html).

In your index.html, make a new element above your root:

```
<div id="portal"></div>
<div id="root"></div>
```

And pass it as a prop in your Select:

```
<Select
  style={{ width: "150px" }}
  dropdownHeight="120px"
  dropdownPosition="top"
  options={options}
  labelField="username"
  valueField="email"
  portal={document.getElementById("portal")}
/>
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/small-wind-64t05)